# link between apps modifying the editing menu (bubble-popup menu) - a similar way to do this

Tags: ios, hyperlink, menu, editing

first of all an Happy New Year to all :)

I have found that it's possible modify the editing menu (copy/paste/select etc) thanks to the UIMenuController menuItems.

I'd like to have a link to my app from other apps through this editing menu, for example a "copy to my app" menu item. Obviously, I can't modify the code of other apps, but is there a way that nears to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called "cloud computing". This is, where you have a web service you send the data to, and then in your other app, on startup or entering the foreground state, you check to see if any new data is available using whatever protocol you design. You have no access to any state of any other application, be it read-only or read-write. I'm sorry.

Comment: When you say "You have no access to any state of any other application" do you mean also the apple apps? For example, I see that if I use Safari and I open a pdf, a sort of toolbar "Open in..." appears (I can chose to open the pdf file in not-apple apps).

Comment: That's a file association that's occurring where you can't see it. You make a call to `-[NSApplication openURL:]` and it opens the url (link to a file, web address, telephone number, whatever) into whatever application is associated with that protocol. This is mutable, and it's well documented. As for apple apps, assume they have the full breadth and run of the system, they are afterall, apple apps, and they do what they want. We however, as third party developers, have rules we have to live by to get onto their playground.