# How to communicate between titainum based iPhone application and native ios application

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

Team,

I'm new to titanium. I'm working on creating enterprise application for iPhone. I need to know is there any way to communicate between two iPhone applications? Where as one application is created as native iPhone application using objective c and other is created using titanium framework.

Kindly share ur thoughts how to do this.

Thanks
Shatthi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Titanium application is actually converted into a native application. You can actually open the build' project in xcode and further develop it there. So there should be no difference to it.

On the other hand, communicating between iPhone apps is not really possible with apps. You can however open links with a prefix to other apps. This is explained here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

I don't know the support for Titanium to actually create the url catchers. It can be done by Xcode as explained in above link. But because you want to communicate TO an native-build app, that app only needs to have the support to understand those links

You could also use this approach: [link between apps modifying the editing menu (bubble-popup menu) - a similar way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574689/link-between-apps-modifying-the-editing-menu-bubble-popup-menu-a-similar-way)